# Crystal Reports seems to have an 80 section per group limit

Tags: c++, crystal-reports, c++builder

Crystal Reports seems to have an 80 section per group limit

```
Environment:
  Microsoft Windows XP
  Professional
  Version 2002
  Service Pack 3

  Crystal Reports XI (Release 1)
  Calling the Crystal Reports Engine crpe32.dll version 11.0.0.1445
  Via Crystal VCL 11 libraries
  Via Borland C++Builder 6 Enterprise Suite Version 6.0 (Build 10.166)
```

I found the report containing 86 sections (in one group)
ran just fine using the Crystal Reports XI exe found at
C:\Program Files\Business Objects\Crystal Reports 11\crw32.exe

However, when I called the same report from an executable compiled 
using Borland C++Builder -> VCL calls -> crpe32.dll
IT DID NOT PRINT.

I spent many frustrating hours debugging the exe.
I used the divide and conquer debugging approach and devised 
a state machine that would do the following while logging every
state along the way:

1. Load the Engine via LoadEngine;
2. Open the Engine via OpenEngine;
3. Open the PrintJob via OpenJob;
4. Close the PrintJob via CloseJob;
5. Close the Engine via CloseEngine;
6. Unload the Engine via UnloadEngine;

I found that the report errored out at OpenJob
with `Crpe1->Status()` status `crsJobFailed`
`Crpe1->LastErrorNumber()` was `"505: No print destination specified"`

Here's the play by play (I output this to a file):

```
  LoadEngine() started
  LoadEngine() completed. The handle to CRPE32.DLL is: 728956928
  EngineOpen() started
  EngineOpen() completed. Engine is already opened.
  JobIsOpen() started.
  JobIsOpen() completed. The PrintJob is open.
  Execute() started
  Status() crsJobFailed
  Execute() failed.
  Error state.
  LastErrorNumber 505: No print destination specified.
  C:\REPORTS\ProblemReport.rpt
  Please first call PEOutputToWindow or PEOutputToPrinter!
  Execute <PEStartPrintJob>
  Finished state.
```

Back to the report:

Deleting some `/*comment*/` sections from the report brought the number of
sections down to 78 and voila ... the report printed out just fine from the
executable compiled on Borland C++Builder -> VCL calls -> crpe32.dll

My conclusion:
Avoid creating over 80 sections in a group.

As a workaround, you can add another group having 
the same `GROUP BY` column (essentially, repeat the 
same group) and create all the extra sections needed 
in the new group (the repeated group).

It's the equivalent of writing the following SQL

```
SELECT 
   column1
   column1
FROM table
GROUP BY 
   column1,
   column1;
```

Has anyone else had this problem?
If yes, what solution have you devised?

Comment: I'm in the process of creating a large report, and I was wondering "How many more sections can I add before I get in trouble". Thanks, now I know. (And sorry I can't answer the question).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because there's no actual question.